# Android libgdx app freezes after onPause() call - always

Tags: android, libgdx

The title is self explanatory. 
The problem occurs (always) when the user presses the home button or the device turns into sleep mode (the screen goes black).
Whenever this happen the app totally freezes, but I can still view the Activity. No exceptions are thrown.

Important aspects: I'm using a view that contains a LibGdx app (open gl) and often set this view visibility to `GONE`.

My approach is that the LibGdx app isnt properly paused and/or resumed.

Any ideas? Please ask for any piece of code if you need any more details!

**EDIT:**

I've confirmed that this only occurs when the open gl view visibility is set to `GONE`.

Comment: Please mention the code of your activity's on pause and onresume code if implemented... Also mention application listner's onpause and on resume calls

Comment: This is an issue that has long been on the LibGDX Issue tracker... https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=817

Comment: Neither onpause or onresume are implemented in my activity. On the application listener these are implemented with no code in the function. Thanks for your help. It seems that theres no solution right now :/